# Enumerate a enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a enum:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum enum1: [:var1, :var2, :var3]
end
```

How can I enumerate `enum1` to get all the values of `enum1` which are `[var1, var2, var3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option is to not do anything with the enum, but rather extract that static array to a constant

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  ENUM_OPTIONS = [:var1, :var2, :var3]

  enum enum1: ENUM_OPTIONS
end
```

Then you'll be able to do `Model1::ENUM_OPTIONS`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Sergio's answer:

```
 Model1.defined_enums['enum1'].keys
```